# css grid repeat layout style list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-grid

I'm creating a grid of a list of items in a cart and I've made an example of the layout just using the grid area but it doesn't repeat itself to make a list how do I make the grid repeat the boxes layout infinitely

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="description"></div>
   <div class="quantity"></div>
   <div class="price"></div>
   <div class="close"></div>

   <div class="description"></div>
   <div class="quantity"></div>
   <div class="price"></div>
   <div class="close"></div>

   <div class="description"></div>
   <div class="quantity"></div>
   <div class="price"></div>
   <div class="close"></div>
   
</div>
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  
}

.close {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
}

.description {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
}

.quantity {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

.price {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / span 1 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>I want to repeat this format of grid row items</h1>

<div class="grid">
  
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="quantity">Quantity</div>
  <div class="price">Price</div>
  <div class="close">Close</div>
  
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="quantity">Quantity</div>
  <div class="price">Price</div>
  <div class="close">Close</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below. I am considering translation to rectify the order:

```css
.grid {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows:50px;
}

.close {
  background: red;
  grid-column:span 2;
  transform:translateY(-200%);
}

.description {
  background: blue;
  grid-column:span 2; 
  transform:translateY(100%);
}

.quantity {
  background: green;
  transform:translateY(100%);
}

.price {
  background: pink;
  transform:translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<h1>I want to repeat this format of grid row items</h1>

<div class="grid">
  
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="quantity">Quantity</div>
  <div class="price">Price</div>
  <div class="close">Close</div>
  
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="quantity">Quantity</div>
  <div class="price">Price</div>
  <div class="close">Close</div>
  
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="quantity">Quantity</div>
  <div class="price">Price</div>
  <div class="close">Close</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using grid-row: 1 / span 2 on .delete and it screws up the layout. I'm not using the height on the divs either this is based on your first answer. I'm trying to get the .delete div to the top for each group

Comment: @ONYX no, you should not define any row, only define the column + translation like in my code